# Sequential Inputs For Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, sequential

What type of neural networks should be used when we have sequential inputs.
 Let say we want to phrase some text which should give output depend on the sequence of the words. For this the output should dependent on the previous state of the inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Recurrent** neural networks are what you are looking for -- at least in the general case, where sequences are long, or not all sequences have the same length.

[Here](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/blob/master/examples/supervised/backprop/backpropanbncn.py)'s an example, [here](http://www.pybrain.org) is a Python implementation and [here](http://www.idsia.ch/~juergen/rnn.html) are some reference papers.